# Calculate Sharpness of Bitmap with Render Script in Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, renderscript

I am able find sharpness of bitmap with Laplacian method using open CV in Android, but the open cv library is heavy and adds significant size to my application. I don't want to add this huge library just for calculating sharpness only. I found on internet that Render Script can do image processing quite efficiently in Android, So I would like to know that is it possible to do bitmap sharpness calculation using render script in Android, if yes please help me to implement that or any other alternate options available for calculating the image sharpness in Android.

Below is the function I used to find sharpness using open CV

```
private float getSharpnessFromOpenCV(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Mat sourceMatImage = new Mat();
    Mat destination = new Mat();
    Mat matGray = new Mat();


    sourceMatImage = Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap);
    Mat kernel = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
    kernel.put(0, 0, 0.0);
    kernel.put(0, 1, -1.0);
    kernel.put(0, 2, 0.0);

    kernel.put(1, 0, -1.0);
    kernel.put(1, 1, 4.0);
    kernel.put(1, 2, -1.0);

    kernel.put(2, 0, 0.0);
    kernel.put(2, 1, -1.0);
    kernel.put(2, 2, 0.0);


    try {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceMatImage, matGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.filter2D(matGray, destination, -1, kernel, new Point());
        Mat median = new Mat();
        Mat std = new Mat();
        Core.meanStdDev(destination, median, std);
        return (float) Math.pow(std.get(0, 0)[0], 2.0);
    } catch (CvException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 50; //default sharpness value
}
```

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible. You can calculate a kernel per pixel with `criptIntrinsicConvolve3x3` and finding the median can be done using a reduce kernel. What steps does OpenCV do and what are your questions for RenderScript?